# Most user friendly way to browse document libraries for saving documents

Tags: document-library, site-collection, save

We are trying to figure out the most user friendly way to save office documents to different site collection document libraries.  The locations appear fine when we click "Save As" for recent folders. We can even click browse and use the up arrow for getting closer to the root path of the site. This works fine, but there is not an easy way navigate to a different site collection. Sure, I can copy/paste the web address in the file path, but I think that is asking too much for basic end users.  Is there a different approach I am not aware of?

Comment: Which office version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user should setup the favorite locations. This is a one time job and they are use it later without much hassle.

1. Open the SharePoint library
2. From Library Tools ribbon click Connect to Office
3. Add to SharePoint Sites
4. When you click Add to SharePoint Sites a message appears to say the library has been added.

Now you can save files to this location from Microsoft Office products. For that

1. Click the File tab and select Save & Send.
2. From the Save & Send menu, select Save to SharePoint. Any site libraries you have recently visited will be displayed in the Recent Locations menu and the Locations menu will display a static list of the sites you have 'added' using the Connect to Office button.

Another solution is using the PIN button available in the RECENT locations. So user need to add the file to a library and pin that location for future use.

Another solution is to open the library in Explorer then add the location to the Favorites. Now the location will be available in File Open/Save dialogue box of office applications.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that is the best way so far.   I would still like a more automated process through group policy or something because now I will have to work with all the end users to set this up.  Also, there will be some administration overhead whenever new libraries are created.  Thanks for your input.